# Django: How to use async tasks in data migrations?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to populate my database using a Data Migration but I'm facing RuntimeWarning and the data is not being inserted.

In my populate function I tried to use Async Await in the api calls this way:

```py
async def populate_table(apps, schema_editor):
    some stuff...
    await api_call_1()...
    for i in range():
       await api_call_2()... #an api call inside a for loop (Async inside Sync is ok?)#
    model.save()
```

And then, I in my migration class:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', 'the previous migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_table)
    ]
```

Running the migration a Runtime Warning is raised:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'populate_table' was never awaited
```

So I tried to decorate my Migration class with Async/Await without success. I did some research and seems I need to use the event loop. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an approach using asgiref's `async_to_sync` and `sync_to_async` works:

```python
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync, sync_to_async

@async_to_sync
async def forward_func(apps, schema_editor):
    await api_call_1()
    for i in range():
        await api_call_2()
    await sync_to_async(model.save)()
```

Synchronous functions that need to access the database should be wrapped in `sync_to_async`, and then awaited.

This can be a little bit tedious, so perhaps a good way is to separate the asynchronous code like this:

```python
def forward_func(apps, schema_editor):
    @async_to_sync
    def get_data_from_the_api():
        ...

    api_data = get_data_from_the_api()
    ...
    model.save()
```